# Mysql results inside a html form

Tags: php, mysql, select

i would like the results inside the form but i cannot get it to work...

```
<form method="post" action="" name="myform">
<div class="overviewLayout">
<label>Naam van de Game:</label>
    <?php
        echo "<select name='naam' id='mySelect'>";
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_game)) {
            echo "<option value='".$row['titel']."'>".$row['titel']."    </option>";
        }
        echo "</select>";
        echo $row['titel']; 

    ?>
<br/>
</div>
</form>
```

The echo echo `$row['titel'];` does not output the current selected title....

edit:

the query i run is like this...

```
$query_game = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM features ORDER BY titel");
```

The while loop displays all the values from a table. When a value is selected i want to display the results of that row from the table.

Comment: You should also post the rest of the code that you are using - especially the SQL query itself.

Comment: show output of `print_r($row);`

Comment: you are using the echo $row['titel'] a few times, which one doesnt print what you want ? The ones inside the while() {} or the one outside ?? If it's the outside one, you are mistaken to expect that - after leaving the while condidion $row is null.

Comment: You are not doing anything to get the selected item first of all.

Answer (score 0):

```
form method="post" action="" name="myform">
<div class="overviewLayout">
<label>Naam van de Game:</label>
    <?php
        echo "<select name='naam' id='mySelect'>";
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_game)) {
            echo "<option value='".$row['titel']."'>".$row['titel']."    </option>";
        }
        echo "</select>";
        echo $row['titel']; 

    ?>
<br/>
</div>
</form>
```

Running this code:

```
<script>
    var e = document.getElementById("mySelect");
    var title= e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
document.write(title);
</script>
```